Product with Long Name Not Found in Storefront Search Using Partial Query
I have a product in Shopware 6 with a long name, such as "XXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXX EXAMPLETEST TG 4 XXXX XXXXX XXXX". When I search for "TG 4" in the storefront, this product is not found. However, when I search for "EXAMPLETEST", the product appears immediately.
Interestingly, in the admin panel search, searching for "TG 4" successfully finds the product as expected.
Is it possible to configure the storefront search in Shopware 6 so that searching for "TG 4" will find this product?
Any advice or guidance on how to adjust the search behavior to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT:
I've tried an entirely new Shopware 6.6.4.1 environment with only this product, and the issue persists: searching for "TG 4" in the storefront still does not find the product.
